# Prevent to execute insert statements to database on laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, query-builder

I have query builder method like this:

```
 public function export_excel($query)
    {
      return DB::select(DB::raw($query));
    }
```

I want to execute `select` statements not `insert` or `update` statements

Comment: You ask this because $query can have a nested insert inside the query?

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: I have no idea what `$query` is, but the only way not to insert an insert query, is to start a transaction, and then roll it back after executing the insert query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the $query checking for unwanted INSERT/UPDATE/etc. with a sql parser.

> Pear: http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser (still fairly new)
>
> txtSQL: http://sourceforge.net/projects/txtsql
>
> PHP-SQL-Parse: http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/ (as mentioned
>   by the OP). This seems to be the most robust of these three (certainly
>   the best documented)

from [sql-parser-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970499/sql-parser-in-php).

But as pointed from @AlonEitan Transaction and Rollback could do the the jobs, but cannot avoid CREATE or DROP (on MySQL).

May be exec that query using **ReadOnly** account can solve the problem with no risks/overhead-executions.